# Issue in connecting titan with hbase

Tags: graph, hbase, titan

I am trying to connect titan(0.5.2) with hbase(0.98.6).

I have started both hadoop and hbase, my JPS command look like below,

```
25824 HRegionServer
24227 NameNode
24403 DataNode
25557 HQuorumPeer
24778 ResourceManager
28412 Jps
25630 HMaster
25007 NodeManager
```

hbase-site.xml:

```
<property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2222</value>
</property>
```

titan-hbase.properties

```
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
```

I have started titan using `./titan.sh start ../conf/titan-hbase.properties` this command.

```
9841 RemoteMavenServer
20643 CassandraDaemon
9381 Main
29512 Jps
21132 Application
27278 Launcher
21071 Elasticsearch
```

and used gremlin console to connect,

`gremlin> TitanFactory.build().set('storage.backend', 'hbase').set('storage.hostname', '127.0.0.1:2222').open()`

But i am not getting any reponse from gremlin console for this command. No error or stacktrace. just not connecting. Can you help me out here, i am totally new to this titan with hbase.

Answer (score 1):

This properties file worked for me with Titan 0.5.4 using `g = TitanFactory.open('/tmp/titan.properties')`:

```
storage.backend=hbase
storage.hostname=127.0.0.1
storage.hbase.ext.hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort=2222
storage.hbase.table=graphtest
```

Using the same properties with the builder `TitanFactory.build()...` did not work though:

> Unknown configuration element in namespace [root.storage.hbase.ext]: zookeeper

Keep in mind that Titan 0.5.2 is quite dated (released in Nov 2014), and it depends on TinkerPop 2.5.0 (released in Apr 2014). Titan and [TinkerPop 2.x](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/incubator-tinkerpop/master/docs/static/images/not-tinkerpop3-gremlin.png) are no longer under active development.

You should consider moving on to [JanusGraph](https://janusgraph.org), which is a fork of Titan, has an active and open community, and is keeping current with the latest releases of [Apache TinkerPop 3.x](https://tinkerpop.apache.org).